# How to integrate tapatalk in my app

Tags: ios, vbulletin, forums

I am working on an app in which I need to show product related forums listing using vBulletine and TAPATALK API like the existing website does.

how could I show it in app?

I googled it alot but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to register at tapatalk.com.

- Then you can "build your own" Tapatalk application [here](http://www.tapatalk.com/custom_app.php), but it's only a customisation of the Tapatalk app. It's a "all-inclusive" app that you can customize. So basically you can't make your "100% own app" using this feature.
- If you need to make your "100% own app", then you can read the API specifications here : [Tapatalk API](http://www.tapatalk.com/api/api_home.php)
  Afaik, there is **no binary / library**, so you have to implement the API by your self.

Comment: Thnx Nial, One more question : if I have talpatalk purchased for my website do i need to purchase again for mobile app? can I use same for both?

Comment: @PrafulKadam "There is no cost for forum owner to activate Tapatalk in your forum", so it's free to install Tapatalk on the forum side. Then you need to pay  for a customisation of Tapatalk application.

Comment: @Nilak : Thnx it means for web it is free, i just need to pay for mobile version right

Comment: @PrafulKadam If you need to customize the Tapatalk app with your Logo and color (for example) : yes you need to pay. See the [FAQ](http://www.tapatalk.com/faq.php)

Comment: @Nilak : I purchased the license and did everything required and downloaded binary but it doesn't provide the source code instead it just gives .apk for android... how do i customized it in this case?